# Testing for file attribute in batch file

Tags: batch-file, file-attributes

I'm writing a batch file and I need to know if a file is read only. How can I do that ?

I know how to get them using the %~a modifier but I don't know what to do with this output. It gives something like -ra------. How can I parse this in batch file ?

Comment: What kind of batch file ? bash, DOS ...  ?

Comment: Windows batch files, as you can see from him mentioning %~a.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
@echo OFF

SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set INPUT=test*

for %%F in (%INPUT%) do (
    set ATTRIBS=%%~aF
    set CURR_FILE=%%~nxF
    set READ_ATTRIB=!ATTRIBS:~1,1!

    @echo File: !CURR_FILE!
    @echo Attributes: !ATTRIBS!
    @echo Read attribute set to: !READ_ATTRIB!

    if !READ_ATTRIB!==- (
        @echo !CURR_FILE! is read-write
    ) else (
        @echo !CURR_FILE! is read only
    )

    @echo.
)
```

When I run this I get the following output:

```
File: test.bat
Attributes: --a------
Read attribute set to: -
test.bat is read-write

File: test.sql
Attributes: -ra------
Read attribute set to: r
test.sql is read only

File: test.vbs
Attributes: --a------
Read attribute set to: -
test.vbs is read-write

File: teststring.txt
Attributes: --a------
Read attribute set to: -
teststring.txt is read-write
```

Comment: Ok this is working for 1 file but if INPUT is a set, ATTRIBS will always have the same value. I tried setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion but it complains when I try to use !ATTRIBS:~1,1! What could I do ?

Comment: Thanks ! For some reason using !ATTRIBS:~1,1! directly in the comparison didn't work but storing it in another variable works.

Answer (score 7):

To test a specific file:

```
dir /ar yourFile.ext >nul 2>nul && echo file is read only || echo file is NOT read only
```

To get a list of read only files

```
dir /ar *
```

To get a list of read/write files

```
dir /a-r *
```

To list all files and report whether read only or read/write:

```
for %%F in (*) do dir /ar "%%F" >nul 2>nul && echo Read Only:  %%F|| echo Read/Write: %%F
```

***EDIT***

[Patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/888385/1012053) fails if the file name contains `!`. This can be solved by toggling delayed expansion on and off within the loop, but there is another way to probe the `%%~aF` value without resorting to delayed expansion, or even an environment variable:

```
for %%F in (*) do for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=a" %%A in ("%%~aF") do (
  if "%%B" equ "" (
    echo "%%F" is NOT read only
  ) else (
    echo "%%F" is read only
  )
)
```