# Batch Files: recursively check for file attributes

Tags: batch-file

I've looked at this topic: [Testing for file attribute in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888264/testing-for-file-attribute-in-batch-file)

The script works perfectly for the specified folder in %INPUT%, but if I want to look into subfolders, it doesn't work. When I add the suggested /R flag, nothing at all happens. Is the syntax correct?

```
for /R %%F in (%INPUT%) do ( ... )
```

thanks
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the base directory immediately after the /R. Whatever is specified in the parentheses will be appended to each subdirectory in the tree. So you can use `.` to get the directory itself:

```
for /R %INPUT% %%F in (.) do ( ... )
```

Also, one weird thing I just discovered is that if you use enabledelayedexpansion syntax, then it doesn't work; it only executes the for body for the base directory, not for any subdirectory. So the following will not work, whether you have enabledelayedexpansion enabled or not:

```
for /R !INPUT! %%F in (.) do ( ... )
```

Another quirk of Dosbatch.

**Edit:** To address your comment, it becomes relevant what `...` contains. This should work if you want to get attributes on both the current iteration directory and files contained within the current iteration directory:

```
for /R %INPUT% %%F in (.) do (attrib %%F& attrib %%F\*)
```

**Edit:** Here's another potential solution, which will likely be slower, but on the other hand might make the code easier to write. But on the other hand, it will have problems with whitespace in file names:

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s %INPUT%') do (attrib %%i)
```

Comment: Thanks, but no that doesn't work. It displays the read/write attribute of the main directory and the subdirectory, but no files.

And yes I've got enabledelayedexpansion set... which (to be honest) I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Maybe my set is wrong? set INPUT=C:\Filenet\Work\Current\IDCMS1\IM\Cloud\Services\Cloudant Adding the \\* at the end does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you don't use

```
attrib /s "%input%"
```

Wheter input is in the form "c:\path\filemask.ext"

Comment: Yes the reason is I want some conditional processing. If the attrib is read-write I want to GOTO: some other section of the batch.